# Different icon themes for launcher and Panel

Tags: unity, icons, customization

Is it possible to have different themes for Panel and Launcher in Ubuntu 16.04 (specifically Unity)?  I have installed `numix` icon themes but don't want to change Panel icons which are by default `ubuntu-mono-dark`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use another icon set while keeping ubuntu mono panel icons**

1. Press ALT+F2 and type "gksu nautilus /usr/share/icons".
2. Make a copy of the "ubuntu-mono-dark" or "ubuntu-mono-light" folder.
3. Rename the folder to a new name.
4. Open the index.theme file
5. Change the "Name" field to a new name ("Name=Ubuntu-Mono-Dark" to "Name=My-New-Icons")
6. Change "Inherits" field to the name of the icon theme you want to use ‘Inherits=Humanity-Dark,gnome,hicolor’ to the name of the folder of the icons you want to use.(This folder may be in ~/.icons or in /usr/share/icons)
7. Save the file and go to appearance preferences to set the new icon theme.

Good luck. You can view full source from this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Icons)